# C: segmentation fault associated with `swprintf`

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

After calling `swprintf` to convert a `char` to a `wchar`, calling a loop triggers a segmentation fault; the statements in the loop header work fine outside the context of the loop. The `swprintf` command is successful based on the return value (3, [which is the number of characters written to the output buffer up to the terminating null character](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/rtref/swprintf.htm)), a fact that can be confirmed by removing the lines for the loop to prevent the segmentation fault. Nevertheless, a `for` or `while` loop called afterwards (or before) produces a segmentation fault. This problem appears to be solved by changing `char* string` to `char string[4]`, implicating a pointer as the source of the problem; given my use case, however, I would rather use a char pointer than a char array. Oddly though, if the loop is removed concomitant with the change of `char*` to `char string[4]`, then a segmentation fault ensues. Thus, some undefined behavior is occurring, likely because of a malformed `swprintf` statement; how can this statement be written properly, and if the statement is malformed, why does it nonetheless produce the expected return value?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

void main() {

  char* string = "ABC";
  //char string[4] = "ABC";
  wchar_t* string_w;
  swprintf(string_w, 4, L"%hs", string);
  int retval = swprintf(string_w, 4, L"%hs", string);
  printf("string: %ls\nreturn value: %d\n",string_w, retval);

  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    // do nothing
  }

}
```

Note: I am compiling using `gcc`: (Debian 6.2.1-5) 6.2.1 20161124.

Comment: Check the answers. You are not allocating memory for `wchar_t *string_w` pointer

Comment: there are only a couple of valid signatures for the `main()` function (regardless of what Visual Basic will allow)  all of them have a return type of `int`, not `void`.  The `gcc` compiler should have warned you about that problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
  wchar_t* string_w;
```

and this

```
  swprintf(string_w, 4, L"%hs", string);
```

without making `string_w` point to valid memory is a recipe for problem. You need to properly initialize `string_w` before using it, e.g.

```
  wchar_t* string_w = malloc(SOME_PROPER_SIZE);
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to allocate the space that `string_w` points to; as it is, it is a pointer that doesn't point anywhere in particular.

Comment: Thanks to both of you.